# Why might there be a gap between an div and the edge of the screen on Chrome and Firefox but fit perfectly on Edge browser?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div that I want to span the entire width of the screen and it works on Edge but not Chrome or Firefox. Here's the CSS for the div:

```
.description-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(23, 64, 139);
    color: white;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Add enough code to the question so that your layout can be tested.

Comment: These are not enough to understand your issue. You need to provide more codes.

Comment: If I add `height: 100%` to the `description-container` rule, `<div class="description-container">` fills the entire viewport in all three browsers. (Note: `min-height` should be used instead.) It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.